# How to add an image in code comment section?

Tags: objective-c, comments, xcode5

I would like to add some image as part of the comments to illustrate which UI the comment is referring to. Is that possible to add an image inside a .h or .m file on Xcode.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
            // 3 looks like a magic number here. But there is logic behind this number
            // 1 row for the program description
            // 1 row for the ratings
            // 1 row for the favorite section
            // then add the count of workouts grouped based on interval
            return 3+_workoutsGroupedBasedOnInterval.count;
}
```

**Update:**
I want to add an image to Objective-C source code(inside a comment section) so that I or my team mates can view the image while viewing source code.

Comment: You mean you want to add an image to your Objective-C source code so you can see the image while viewing the code in Xcode? Is so, no, can't be done.

Comment: How about trying something like http://picascii.com or http://www.glassgiant.com/ascii/ ???